# IBM Mobile Quality Assurance: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I have followed this tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/quality-assurance/8.0/cordova/

If I run the app, it throws the following error:

> 2016-06-30 11:51:29.181 HelloWorld[8767:236400] -[MQACordovaPlugin initWithWebViewEngine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff8d5a21ad0
>
> 2016-06-30 11:51:29.182 HelloWorld[8767:236400] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  -[MQACordovaPlugin initWithWebViewEngine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff8d5a21ad0

Here is the history of my terminal:

```
Sebastians-MBP:mqatest:$ cordova create hello com.example.hello  HelloWorld
Creating a new cordova project.
Sebastians-MBP:mqatest:$ cd hello/
Sebastians-MBP:hello:$ cordova platform add ios
Adding ios project...
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.1.1
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Sebastians-MBP:hello:$ cordova plugin add /Users/Sebastian/temp/CordovaPlugin-3.0.18
Installing "com.ibm.mqa" for ios
Sebastians-MBP:hello:$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for ios
Sebastians-MBP:hello:$ cordova plugin list
com.ibm.mqa 3.0.18 "IBM MobileFirst Quality Assurance"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
Sebastians-MBP:hello:$ cordova build
```

Building in xcode works fine and the app is starting, but MQA is not working.
Seems to be something wrong in my environment. This is my cordova version:

```
Sebastians-MBP:hello:$ cordova -version
6.2.0
```

I've also uploaded the project [here](https://ibm.box.com/s/f7kixuhk7mlox73y6dyh9b87h2zjzelm) (removed my app key, but still the same result in xcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your iOS platform and change your iOS runtime to 3.7.

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios@3.7
```

Comment: This is not good though, MFPF8 requires cordova-ios@4.0.1 or above; it seems that currently MQA does not support MFPF 8.0. @sebastian, feel free to open a PMR.

Comment: The project in this question isn't using MFP 8.

Comment: Okay, so regardless we have a problem. :)

Comment: That solves this problem, but I can't agree more to Idan. I'll open a PMR